# trouble reading from __global memory after atom_inc in OpenCL

Tags: memory, opencl

OpenCL doesn't have a global barrier that will stop all threads, so I'm trying to create a work around with the following code:

```
void barrier(__global uint* scratch) {
  uint nThreads = get_global_size(0);
  atom_inc(scratch);
  /* this loop never terminates */
  while(scratch[0] < nThreads) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

The idea is that each thread loops until all of them increment that one piece of memory.

However, the value read from scratch[0] never changes for the threads once it's been read, and it loops forever. I know it's being incremented because it's the correct value when I read it back to the host.

Is the global memory being locally cached? What's going on here?

Comment: What platform/drivers/etc. are you testing this on?

Comment: why would you want to do this? Synchronizing across workgroups can not work, because they might not run concurrently. And even if this would work: atleast for gpus (opencl for cpu only doesn't make sense...) its going to be incredibly slow, since it has to serialize all those accesses to global memory. So even if you use only 10000 threads (which would execute completely concurrently on middle to highend gpus) and atomics operate onchip (so fermi only) such a barrier will still cost >1000000 cycles (each thread has several cycles latency for both reading and writing, one thread at a time)

Comment: The standard way of using global synchronization in opencl is starting a new kernel, which should be much faster for reasonable threadcounts (I'm not sure about nvidia right now, but amd puts 225µs as kernellauch latency, while a global barrier like this would cost several ms.

Comment: That workgroups don't necessarily run concurrently is the key fact I didn't know, and it's why I posted that at the answer below. I was less concerned with performance since I only have to do this once per execution.

Comment: If performance doesn't matter there is even less reason not to simply split the functionality into several kernels and use the launch of a new kernel as a synchronization point (of course since bigger kernels means more registers/thread having smaller kernels can even improve performance). Besides I would still think there are performance considerations in the long run, because why else use opencl. But I just wanted to clarify why this is a bad idea even if it would work, afterall others might try with less workgroups ;).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the order in which work groups are executed is implementation defined. This means that some threads might start only **after** others have finished.

In the code I gave, the work groups that are started first will loop forever waiting on the the others to hit the 'barrier'. And the work groups that would be started later won't ever start because they're waiting for the first ones to finish.

If the implementation (I'm on a Radeon 5750, using Stream SDK 2.2) executes all work groups concurrently, then it probably wouldn't be an issue. But that's not the case for my setup.